# Maximal Ideals in the Ring of Complex Entire Functions

Tags: analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $X = \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of all continuous real-valued functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. For $x \in [0,1]$, let $$M_{x} = \{ f \in X \ | \ f(x)=0\}.$$ One can show by using compactness of $[0,1]$ that every maximal ideal is of this form.

**Extending the question to entire functions**: Let $\mathsf{C}(z)$ be the ring of complex entire functions. For $ \lambda \in \mathsf{C}$ let $M_{\lambda}$ denote the set of all entire functions which have a zero at $\lambda$. Then is $M_{\lambda}$ a maximal ideal in $\mathsf{C}(z)$, and does every ideal happen to be of this form? I don't know how to prove this!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No.

Let $f(z)=1/\Gamma(z)$ where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.
Then $f$ vanishes at $0$, $-1,-2,\ldots$ and nowhere else. For integers
$m$ let $f_m(z)=f(z+m)$. Then $f_m$ vanishes at $-m,-m-1,\ldots$.
Let $I$ be the ideal of the ring of the entire functions generated by the $f_m$.
Then $I$ is proper, since otherwise finitely many of the $f_m$
would generate an ideal containing the constant function $1$. But
any finite set of $f_m$ have a common zero, so this doesn't hold.
So $I\subseteq J$ for some maximal ideal $J$ (using the standard Zorn's
lemma argument). But $J\ne M_\lambda$ for any $\lambda$, as for each $\lambda$
there is some $m$ with $f_m(\lambda)\ne0$, and $f_m\in J$.

Comment: Nice! Btw, when you say "$f$ is proper", you mean "$I$ is [a] proper [ideal]", don't you?

Comment: Chapman, can I consider ideal I generated by $f_i$ ($i\in\mathbb{Z}$)  where $f_i$ is an entire function which vanishes at all integers except $i$?

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly from my student days, if D is a connected domain in the complex plane, then the ring *O*(D) of holomorphic functions on D has the property that every finitely generated ideal is actually principal, but there are ideals that cannot be finitely generated (such as in Robin's answer above).

Answer (score 1):

No.

For the purposes of this note, I'll say that a function $g$ is *almost entire* if it has the form $g={\text{entire}\over \text{polynomial}}$.
Let $f$ be an entire function. Then we get an ideal $I(f)$ in the ring of entire functions, by letting $I(f)$ consist of all functions of the form
$f g$ such that
$g$ is almost entire and $fg$ is entire.

If $f$ has infinitely many zeroes, and $g$ is almost entire, then the denominator of $g$ can cancel at most finitely many of the zeroes of $f$, so  $fg$ will be zero at infinitely many of the points where $f$ is zero. Then
$I(f)$ is a proper ideal.

Also, if $f$ is not identically zero, then for every point $a \in \mathbb{C}$,we can divide $f$ by an appropriate power of $z-a$ to obtain an element of  $I(f)$  that does not vanish at $a$. That is, $I(f)$ is not contained in the ideal of functions vanishing at $a$.